# Adding Google Maps to a View in Swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have the following dilemma.
I created a 2 view in my project ( GMContainer and GMHolder). I want GMHolder inside all his view to display the Google Maps map.

Unfortunate I am just able to add a Google Maps view in the middle of my entire view and can't make it inside a view I created. Also I don't know what to add to the mapView as frame. I tried creating a new CGRect and adding the value of the view, adding my view, but id doesn't seem to do the trick...
 Any tips on how to change the last rows to make Google Maps display on the entirety of GMHolder?

```
    let GMContainer : UIView = {
       let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        return view
    }()

    var GMHolder : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        return view
    }()

 func setupUI() {
        GMContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        GMHolder.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(GMContainer)
        view.addSubview(GMHolder)


        GMContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryBox.bottomAnchor , constant: 32).isActive = true
        GMContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
        GMContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        GMContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 450).isActive = true

        GMHolder.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GMContainer.topAnchor , constant: 40).isActive = true
        GMHolder.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GMContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
        GMHolder.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: GMContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
        GMHolder.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true

//GM View Code

                var mapView : GMSMapView


        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.321262, longitude: -122.378945, zoom: 10)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: GMHolder.frame.origin.x, y: GMHolder.frame.origin.y , width: 300, height: 300), camera: camera)
     //   mapView.center = self.view.center

        view.addSubview(mapView)
       GMHolder = mapView
```

[Photo of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJJzI.jpg) as you can see, it isn't bounded to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Init inside the GMHolder everything, it seems to do the trick.

```
 var GMHolder : GMSMapView = {
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(API_KEY)
         let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 37.321262, longitude: -122.378945, zoom: 12)
        let view = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        return view
    }()
```